# Retornando o valor NULL

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, conexão, null

Alguém pode ajudar-me, estou fazendo um código para inserir dados numa tabela no Banco de Dados e atualizar também, mas infelizmente não está dando certo, todas as variáveis estão dando `NULL` e o próprio código que seleciona a tabela também dá `NULL` quando faço o var_dum().

No entanto onde está o erro? Já verifiquei varias vezes, a conexão com a base de dados esta tudo bem porque mostra outras tabelas k também tem conexão só quando faço o POST para inserir k não aceita. Só mostra o valor da variável quando faço um erro de propósito na seleção da tabela. Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['button'])) {

$code_aluno=$_POST['code_aluno'];
$disciplina=$_POST['disciplina'];
$id_trabalho= $_POST['id_trabalho'];
$nota = $_POST['nota'];
$id = $_GET['id'];


$sql_trb_bimestra = "SELECT * FROM trabalhos WHERE id ='$id_trabalho'";

$resulta_trb_bimestre = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_trb_bimestra);

while ($res_trb_bimestre = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta_trb_bimestre)) {

$bimestre = $res_trb_bimestre['bimestre'];

$sql_post = "UPDATE envio_trabalho SET status = 'Accepted', nota = '$nota' WHERE id = '$id_trabalho' AND discipline ='$disciplina'";
mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_post);

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO nota_trabalho (code, bimestre, discipline, nota) VALUES ('$code_aluno', '$bimestre', '$nota' )";

mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_insert);

echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='';</script>";
}
}var_dump($disciplina)

?>
```

Comment: Logo abaixo de `if(isset($_POST['button'])) {` coloca um `print_r($_POST);` e mostra pra nós o que está sendo enviado no post.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse trecho:

```
INSERT INTO nota_trabalho (code, bimestre, discipline, nota)
VALUES ('$code_aluno', '$bimestre', '$nota' )
```

Está faltando o valor correspondente a `discipline`. Veja:

```
INSERT INTO nota_trabalho (code, bimestre, discipline, nota)
VALUES ('$code_aluno', '$bimestre', '$disciplina' , '$nota' )
```